# JavaFX ComboBox displaying object not it's property

Tags: javafx, combobox, observablecollection

i have built GUI with combo box. I have `ObservableList<SimpleTableObject> types`
which should display types of material. It looks like this

```
 material_comboBox_type.getItems().addAll(types);

    material_comboBox_type.setCellFactory((ListView<SimpleTableObject> 
    param) -> {
          final ListCell<SimpleTableObject> cell = new 
     ListCell<SimpleTableObject>() {                
            @Override
            public void updateItem(SimpleTableObject item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {

                    setText(item.getName().get());//return String, actuall name of material

                }
                else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    });
```

Now the problem is this: when i click combobox, it shows names as desired. But when i select one, instead of the string property, an object itself is displayed, which looks like that `classes.SimpleTableObject@137ff5c`.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected item in a combo box is displayed in a cell called the [`buttonCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#buttonCellProperty). So you need to set the button cell as well as the cell factory (which generates the cells in the dropdown).

To do this, it's probably easier to refactor your cell implementation as a (named) inner class:

```
private static class SimpleTableObjectListCell extends ListCell<SimpleTableObject> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(SimpleTableObject item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null) {

            setText(item.getName().get());//return String, actuall name of material

        }
        else {
            setText(null);
        }
    }

}
```

And then:

```
materialComboBoxType.setCellFactory(listView -> new SimpleTableObjectListCell());
materialComboBoxType.setButtonCell(new SimpleTableObjectListCell());
```

Comment: The class could be declared in the method too. Also you could simply use the factory to create the button cell: `materialComboBoxType.setButtonCell(materialComboBoxType.getCellFactory().call(null));`

Comment: @fabian `materialComboBoxType.call(null)` -> `materialComboBoxType.getCellFactory().call(null)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did this with converter:

```
material_comboBox_type.setConverter(new StringConverter<SimpleTableObject>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(SimpleTableObject object) {
            return object.getName().get();
        }

        @Override
        public SimpleTableObject fromString(String string) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
```